# How do I save specific responses from webservers in my local computer

Tags: php, web-applications, autosave, browser-extension

I have been asked to write to save the data in some secure place after certain task is completed by a client.

Here my client has alot of staffs who makes data entry in online forms provided by some different vendors. After some steps the entered data generates some results. i.e after submitting the web form. Now he wants the generated results to be saved either in local computer or in some online server.

Can it be done by:

1.) Creating a local web server which sits in between the users and the online main third party server and record all the generated results?

2.) Creating a browser extension [m thinking about firefox] and forcing users to navigate via the specific browser and record all the generated results?

**I am pretty sure that second method can work as firebug is doing that only need to add some functionality to save the data.

any idea will be appreciated.

Sorry for mis-leading guys. To make more clear here are some more explanation.

a.) I am writing application to one of my client who has many staffs who enters data in abc.com website.
b.) User submits the data to abc.com.
c.) the website abc.com produces or generates some result as per input data and sends back to user.
d.) Now I need a system which will be inbetween the staffs/user and abc.com website and track the responses of abc.com and save it to some location automatically.
e.) Currently the data entry user will manually save the result to his local computer and if he/she forgets to save then we miss the result so want to do it automatically so that we wont be missing any single result.

Answer (score 0):

A local webserver wouldn't really help so much because of crossdomain issues, unless you wanna go with something as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP). In that case, you might wanna use a signed java applet, which (assuming the user accepts the certificate) has any access an installed Java app would have, so it could potentially bind a port and server as HTTP server (I'm not sure how well this works on linux or unix).

Another idea would be to use Flash's [local shared objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html?allClasses=1#flush%28%29). Depends on how much data you want to save. You may need to make the Flash visible, so the user can see the dialog for allowing the data to be saved. You can communicate from JavaScript to Flash using [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?allClasses=1).

Yet the most simple thing is to give the user a permanent cookie, and save the data associated with that cookie on a web server.

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at HTML5 local storage if you don't need a lot of data to be stored or you can use local databases, see http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/ .

You can also sync it with a server once the client is online again..

Comment: One of the many great HTML5 features, I have to say. The thing is, it's a little ahead of time to rely on them.